# Groovy integration testing with executor service

Tags: java, testing, groovy, concurrency, integration

I want to test optimistic locking on my resource. To do that I want to call my endpoint let's say 10 times and assert that in my database I only get 1 record. My test:

```
given:
def request = someRequest()

when:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10)
10.times {
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        restTemplate.postForEntity(localUri() + "/resource", request, String.class)
        latch.countDown()
    })
}
latch.await()

then:
storage.findAll().size() == 1
```

Everytime I run this test I see that there are exactly 5 attempts while I expect 10 calls. As a database I use PostgreSQL image. I'm not an expert with concurrency, do you know where is the problem?

Comment: How do you see there are only 5 calls?

Comment: If you replace your `postForEntity` with a regular `log.info('Execute called')` , you can clearly see there are 10 calls and everything works fine. Therefore, the issue is most likely somewhere within the `/resource` endpoint. It would certainly be useful to see what it does.

Comment: By the way, your problem is fit for the new *Project Loom* features being previewed and incubated in Java 19: virtual threads and structured concurrency. See Java JEPs.